# fdisk -l only displays boot partition

Tags: storage-area-network, mount, partition, fdisk, parted

I have a SAN, and it's able to read and write to the 50TB RAID just fine, but when I run

```
fdisk -l
```

it only lists the boot partition of the SAN server, and doesn't display anything about the other partitions on the RAID. I've also tried using

```
parted -l
```

with the same result. Now when I type

```
mount
```

it shows that the partitions are mounted just fine. I've never seen this happen. The box is running Openfiler 2.3 (I know it's old, we're in the process of upgrading all our old equipment). We have another SAN that's configured almost identically, and it's able to display the partition info with either of the two commands I mentioned above.

Comment: Are you using iSCSI?

Comment: No, it's fibre channel

Answer (score -1):

You can not partition hard disks remotely in the manor. You must have direct access to the block device as to modify the partitioning table you must first unmount it. If you want to repartition the disks use the tools that are appropriate for your SAN. If you are simply after more information about free space and such use `df -h`

Comment: It's quite usual in a SAN (e.g. FibreChannel or iSCSI) to see the storage available as block devices which you can indeed partition as you like on the machine that can see it.

Comment: I'm not trying to partition anything. All I want to do is display all the partitions available to the machine. The Openfiler box is hooked directly up to the RAID.

Comment: I edited my question for clarity.

Comment: You didn't say anything about iSCSI in your original post SAN could have meant any number of things. Shame about the downvote though :/